# Building a Discord bot to DM'd a particular user - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to discord.py and Python programming in general. I'm attempting to code a bot that can DM'd users by reacting to an `on_message` event (like typing a "send a DM" would be followed by a DM sent to that certain person.) But when I try to get the user, it results in: `AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`. My guess is that it has to do something with the ID of the person I'm taking, but I have no idea what is wrong about it. And even if I am so sure that this ID does actually exist (I can't have copied the wrong IDs right? Right click on the user's name and there's that "Copy ID" option at the end of the list that pops up...) It works completely fine if I let the bot send a DM to the author of the message, who is myself, (and perhaps because the code doesn't involve getting an ID.)

Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  content = message.content
  if message.author == client.user:
     return
  
  #DM'd users
  if content == 'send a DM!':
     user = client.get_user(<the user's ID here, it's an int>)
     await user.send('hello')
     await message.author.send('hello') #it works when sending myself a DM
  await client.process_command(message)
```

The full response informing me the error I got was:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X100e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/X100e/Documents/code/Python/bot.py", line 73, in on_message
    await user.send('hello')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Hopefully I can have some advice on how to fix this!

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: I don't. What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that you're trying is simply `None`, a nonetype doesn't have any attributes, in order to fix that you need to enable intents, [here's how](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Also remember, you need `intents.members` so you also need to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), a guide is also available in the first link.

Comment: I have enabled the intents in the developer portal, though I'm not sure if I did right through codes because it still returns the same error. Is adding `intents = discord.Intents.default()` and `intents.members = True` everything?

Comment: did you pass it in the client instance? Like so: `client = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)` or if you're using `discord.Client`: `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

Comment: I did that too! Sorry, forgot to mention of it.

Comment: and your question is..?

Comment: It still doesn't work with that same NoneType error thing. I wonder if there's still anything i need to fix?

Comment: I copied the code and change the ID, and it works flawlessly for me, I'm not sure what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Actually, after a few more test runs, it worked now! But seems like that only happened after I'd tried to play around with the DMs scanning settings of Discord, though I don't even know if there's actually anything to do with it, in the first place; it just runs smoothly now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: no worries, remember to accept the answer if it helped